# DataStore vs SQLite - Sencha Touch

Tags: sqlite, sencha-touch

A rookie question. Can any one explain when it is better to go with SQLite storage in sencha touch and when to go with use data stores.

regards,

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they are mutually exclusive.

Sencha Touch stores come into their own when you have any kind of data that needs displaying in the viewport (and that data might change)

Sencha have a sql proxy that will work on these stores with a browser's websql implementation or a native app's sqlite implementation (with the aid of a cordova/phonegap plugin)

The main reason why you'd use SQLite on a native app is to circumvent the 5mb localstorage limit. You can't get around this limit for webapps though.